# Why do electronic ‘holes’ in semi conductors have opposite wave vectors, but identical velocities to the electrons they pair with?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

In my condensed matter physics course we were discussing the properties of electronic holes in semi conductors. We concluded that in order to conserve momentum, the electronic holes must have a wave vector opposite to that of the electron to which they pair. I thought that since the wave vector is linked with the direction of propagation, this means electronic holes have the opposite velocity to their associated electron. 
However, we were shown that the velocity of the holes are identical to the velocity of their paired electron, this arguement was made by considering the conservation of current in the valence band.

How is it possible for the wave vector of the hole to have an opposite sign to that of the electrons, but both travel in the same direction?

Comment: I seem to remember that this is dependent upon sign conventions in various places. In particular, I think you're working in the convention where the hole mass is negative?

Comment: Holes are not 'paired' or associated with electrons. There are electrons, and there are empty electron states (holes).

Comment: My bad, since an excited electron always leaves an empty electron state (hole), I thought it made sense to say the two are paired together.

Comment: @jacob1729 yes, we are working in a convention where electronic holes in the valence band will have the opposite effective mass of an electron in that band.